# Special alignment

Tags: align, arrays

[image]

Can anyone tell me how you can I do such alignment in an efficient way? I tried several things within the array but I didn't find the way.

Comment: That is just multline, however I'd not recommended it in this case. Reads like a lot better with the three obvious <= aligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either `multline` (but I'd avoid it) or `split`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

The multline version
\begin{multline}
II^2\le
  \int_{2\theta(j-5)r^{}_{\!B}}^{\infty}
  \int_X
  \bigl|\bigl(
    t^{2(M+1)}L^{M+1}e^{-t^2L}b
  \bigr)(y)\bigr|^{2}
  \,d\mu(y)\frac{dt}{t^{4M+1}}
\\
\le
  C(2^{\theta j}r^{}_{\!B})^{-4M}
  \lVert b\rVert_{L^{2}(X)}^{2}
\le
  C\cdot 2^{-j(4\theta M-n_{0})}\cdot 2^{-jn_{0}}V(B)^{-1}
\\
\le
  C\cdot 2^{-j(4\theta M-n_{0})}V(2^{j}B)^{-1}
\end{multline}
and the split version
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
II^2&\le
  \int_{2\theta(j-5)r^{}_{\!B}}^{\infty}
  \int_X
  \bigl|\bigl(
    t^{2(M+1)}L^{M+1}e^{-t^2L}b
  \bigr)(y)\bigr|^{2}
  \,d\mu(y)\frac{dt}{t^{4M+1}}
\\[.5ex]
&\le
  C(2^{\theta j}r^{}_{\!B})^{-4M}
  \lVert b\rVert_{L^{2}(X)}^{2}
\\[1ex]
&\le
  C\cdot 2^{-j(4\theta M-n_{0})}\cdot 2^{-jn_{0}}V(B)^{-1}
\\[1ex]
&\le
  C\cdot 2^{-j(4\theta M-n_{0})}V(2^{j}B)^{-1}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Note some improvements I made: no `\left` and `\right` and some adjustments for *r* with the *B* subscript.

[image]

Comment: Why would you avoid `multlined`?

Comment: @Bernard It doesn't clearly show the chain of inequalities.

Comment: Yes, in such configuration, you're right. Btw, I never really understtod if there's a difference between `split` and `aligned`. Could you shed some light on it?

Comment: @Bernard `split` can be used also inside `align` and will keep the outside alignment point.

Comment: Well, `aligned` can also be used inside `align`, or do I miss something?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, but in some cases `split` is better. The main difference, however, is that `split` obeys the `tbtags` option, which `aligned` doesn't: with `\begin{aligned}[t]` the number will go at the top anyway.

Comment: +1 for `r^{}_{\!B}` -- nice touch! Certainly much more appealing output than what's produced by `r_B`.

Comment: @Mico I knew you'd like it. I could visually spot `r_{B}` from the OP's image and immediately typed `r^{}_{B}`. But I saw the B too far especially in the subscript. It's possibly a bit too near in normal size, but without any other subscript around, maybe it's better this way.